# Obtener rango entre dos horas dadas

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Actualmente estoy trabajando con momentjs y moment-range para mostrar en un array el rango entre dos fechas dadas, éste es mi código:

```
var start = moment("2017-01-03", 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var end   = moment("2017-01-13", 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
var rangoFechas = moment().range(start,end);
var resultado =rangoFechas.toArray('days'); 
for(var i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++){
    var dia=resultado[i].format('dddd, D/MMMM/YYYY');
    console.log(dia)
}
```

Ahora debo implementar la misma lógica pero envés de fechas debo poner horas, he intentado lo siguiente:

```
var start = moment("15:00:00", 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm:ss');
var end   = moment("19:00:00", 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm:ss');
var rangoHoras = moment().range(start,end);
var resultado =rangoHoras.toArray('hours'); //será hours?
for(var i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++){
    var hora=resultado[i].format('HH:mm');
    console.log(hora)
}
```

Y la verdad es que no he podido obtener nada. 
Cómo lo puedo solucionar?.
De antemano les agradezco

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo un ejemplo para restar horas y así obtener el intervalo, como en dentro de tu bucle usas el formato 'HH:mm' utilizo ese mask para declarar los tipos.

```
var start = moment.duration("13:45", "HH:mm"),
    end = moment.duration("14:30", "HH:mm"),
    diff = end.subtract(start);
diff.hours();
diff.minutes();
```

También tienes el método .diff en los objetos que te podría valer, en la documentación de [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) viene especificado